# extract dropdown boxe's value in php

Tags: php, html

I have small problem here. I have dropdown box in my form with 2 values; i.e Active and Inactive with Active being selected by default. I want to extract the selected value from the drop down box in PHP. I,m new to PHP and dont know how to do the same. Pls help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the name of the form field? Is this a POST or GET request? What are the `value=''` bits on those two fields?

Comment: After `GET` or `POST`, what you get is only the selected item. If the object name is 'status', check for `$_GET['status']` or `$_POST['status']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="your_select">
    <option value="active" selected">Active</option>
    <option value="inactive"">Inactive</option>
</select>
...
<?php
$isActive = !empty($_POST['your_select']) ? $_POST['your_select'] : null;
?>
```

*Note: The sample above is assuming your form method is post.*

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted by the user, to your PHP script, you'll find the submitted data in either [**`$_GET`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [**`$_POST`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) -- depending on the method of the form.

Using the [**`var_dump()`**](https://www.php.net/var_dump) function, you'll be able to see what's in those :

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

or

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

will show you what's inside those variables ;-)